# Why i am getting same p values for different categorical variables when i used one way anova in r?

Tags: r, categorical-data, anova

I have a dependent variable as of type continuous and independent variable(4) as of type categorical with more than 2 levels(unordered).

```
 dput(head(subset_data,5))
structure(list(cat1 = structure(c(15L, 7L, 
15L, 13L, 7L)), class = "factor"),cat2 = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L)), class = "factor"), 
cat3 = structure(c(51L, 51L, 46L, 46L, 44L)), class = "factor"), 
cat4 = structure(c(1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 2L)),  class = "factor"),
var1 = c(27L, 36L, 10L,9L, 26L)), row.names = c(32L, 33L, 38L, 40L, 41L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried one way anova test to know association between var1 and categorical variables.Output is like below.

```
var1 vs cat1 :
aov_cat1 <- aov(var1 ~ cat1, data = subset_data)
# Summary of the analysis
summary(aov_cat1)
Output:
           Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq  F value   Pr(>F)    
cat1       14   6686217   477587   285.9     <2e-16 ***
Residuals  97691 163185376 1670                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

```
var1 vs cat2 :
aov_cat2 <- aov(var1 ~ cat2, data = subset_data)
# Summary of the analysis
summary(aov_cat2)
Output:
                Df    Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
cat2            5    488349   97670   56.34 <2e-16 ***
Residuals     97700 169383244 1734                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

```
var1 vs cat3 :
aov_cat3 <- aov(var1 ~ cat3, data = subset_data)
# Summary of the analysis
summary(aov_cat3)
Output:

           Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq  F value Pr(>F)    
cat3       51   14882835  291820   183.9   <2e-16 ***
Residuals 97654 154988758 1587                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

```
var1 vs cat4 :
aov_cat4 <- aov(var1 ~ cat4, data = subset_data)
# Summary of the analysis
summary(aov_cat4)
               Df    Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value   Pr(>F)    
cat4           3    4851874  1617291   957.5   <2e-16 ***
Residuals   97702  165019719 1689                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I am getting pr(>F) value same for 4 categorical variables w.r.t var1 and F values are high .What is the interpretation of that and can we visualize the association between continuous and categorical variables?

Can we use one way anova for the association between continuous vs categorical variables(for more than 2 levels).

Please,suggest me ideas on this.

Comment: The P-value is not the same, it's just being reported as below the machine precision. Your F-statistics are all very large, and hence the P-values are very small.

Comment: How to conclude which variable association is more in this case?

Comment: Well firstly, I wouldn't fit the four variables separately. At the very least you should try something like `var1~cat1+cat2+cat3+cat4` - and you have more than enough data to fit the full model  `var1~cat1+cat2+cat3+cat4` . The issue with the second one is that it will be very hard to interpret because there are 4*52*6*16 = 19,968 model terms. So fit just the main effects model (the first one I wrote), and look at the relative size of the sums of squares or the mean squares. The one with the largest mean square is probably what I'd choose (initially).

Comment: What is the reason behind choosing the largest mean square values? Generally, we look for the p value and F value.

Comment: If you're looking down the sum of squares column, then you can think of the SS for a particular variable divided by the sum of the whole column as "the proportion of variation in the response explained by that variable." You need to temper that a little bit, because if a factor has lots of levels, then it uses LOTS of degrees of freedom (one of your factors has 52 levels). The F-tests (and associated P-vals) will tell you about significance but you need to think about the trade off in complexity. I will add another comment below

Comment: Models with interactions can often show significant interaction effects, but when you look at the proportion of extra variation explained by these terms, it is often better to just ignore it, because it isn't really adding anything to the informativeness of the model.